# Is adding the "Immahot" (matriarchs) to the Amidah permitted?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, avot-patriarch-fathers, reform-judaism

Many non-traditional congregations have modified the Avot prayer opening the Amidah, to add the Immahot. For example:

[image]

(Form [Shabbat Siddur of the](https://nfty.org/wp-content/uploads/sites/32/2016/05/Siddur.pdf) *First Reform Minyan in UC Berkeley* 2003)

What is the halachah on this?

The Talmud says that "we may not alter the coin that the Sages have minted -- *En lecha reshut l'hosif 'al matbea' shetav'u chachamim bivrachot*" [Berachot Y 86a].  This means that the prayers and blessings in the siddur may not be changed.  That way, you can pray in any synagogue in the world and you will use the exact same words, and feel at home.  That makes us one people.

Yet obviously the siddur has grown over the centuries.  The Talmud does not forbid adding new prayers.  We have seen the addition of many favorites, such as:

Lecha dodi -- 16th cent.; 
Shalom Alechem -- 15th cent.; 
Yigdal -- 15th cent.; 
Adon Olam -- 11th cent.; 
Prayer for Israel -- 1948; 
En kelohenu -- 9th cent.; 
kEl Adon -- 8th cent.; 
Hamavdil -- 11th cent.; 
Maoz Tzur -- 13th cent.; 
Yedid nefesh -- 16th cent.;

So, can we conclude that we may add a completely separate prayer extolling women (if that's what a congregation wants) without breaking halacha, but not make it part of the Amidah, which must remain in fixed form?

Comment: Are you discussing the addition of the אמהות after ﭏקי אבהרם…ﭏקי יעקב, in the conclusion of מגן אברהם, or both ?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt It sounds like he's proposing a standalone prayer naming them not in the Amida

Comment: @DoubleAA -- I am not "proposing" anything.  I am personally opposed to changes.

Comment: SHUA O"H 126 says one who "makes mistakes" (טועה) in the first 3 Brochos must recite them from the beginning, presumably hinting that the mistakes invalidate the Teffila (as the first 3 Brochos invalidate the whole Teffila). Now the question is if those additions can be considered "a mistake" or not. See https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.119.1?lang=he&with=Mishnah%20Berurah&lang2=he and MB there.

Comment: Not a single thing on your list is a prayer. They’re all just piyutim. Selichos might be a better parallel.

Comment: Note that for ideological reasons such as this it is undeniably not permitted. If we're talking about the hypothetical case that it wasn't ideologically driven then it gets interesting.

Comment: Worth noting that Prof. Daniel Sperber cites numerous early versions of the Amida which include variations on the text we have today, even in the first and final berachot.

Comment: [D. Golinkin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Golinkin) (Responsa in a Moment vol. 2, pp. 53) attempts to prove that according to traditional *halachah* it is prohibited -at least *lechathilah*- to make any such emendation to the *amidah*.